# Ошибка при сохранении изменений ответа

Tags: дефект

- написал и опубликовал ответ на ruSO
- после сохранения решил внести небольшие коррективы
- внес изменения, нажал на кнопку "Сохранить изменения"
- после чего происходит ошибка:

  - со страницы удаляется содержимое ответа
  - выводится сообщение: *Вы начали редактировать сообщение. Отказаться от правки?*

> **Замечания:**
> Подобное поведение действительно пугает, но при попытке открыть эту же страницу на другой вкладке видно, что внесенные изменения были сохранены и содержимое ответа в порядке.
> Тем не менее поведение редактора является некорректным, не соответствует выполненным пользователем действиям, вводит пользователя в заблуждение...ну и пугает, конечно)

[image]

- после нажатия на одну из кнопок, содержимое ответа появляется обратно
- однако, состояние поста сохраняется некорректно и при попытке уйти со страницы выводится еще одно предупреждение

---

Данное поведение у меня воспроизводится на всех (моих, естественно) ответах.
На чужих не проверял, но что-то мне подсказывает что там ситуация аналогичная.
В консоли никаких ошибок при этом не выводится.
Правда в ответ на правку в запросах можно увидеть 204ый ответ, что немного смущает и что возможно и является причиной ошибки

---

**UPD:**

на мете при сохранении ответа поведение также воспроизводится

Comment: Подтверждаю. Любое редактирование (что вопроса, что ответа, что своего, что чужого) и нажатие затем любой кнопки (сохранения, отказа) приводит к подобному сообщению. Наблюдается на всех (моих во всяком случае) SO-сайтах, не зависит от браузера (IE, Edge, FF, Chrome, Opera), не лечится очисткой кэша. Уже третий, кажется, день...

Comment: @Михаил Ребров подтверждаю, тоже сегодня вздрогнул при редактировании поста

Comment: `Уже третий, кажется, день` у меня только сегодня обнаружилось.

Comment: На текущий момент ошибка(лично у меня) больше не воспроизводится. По всей видимости уже пофиксили(хотя это не точно... она как-то в разное время воспроизводилась у всех)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На текущий момент ошибка(лично у меня) больше не воспроизводится.

На мете stackexchange под аналогичным постом с данной ошибкой нашел следующий [ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375068/422187) от сотрудника:

> First of all: thanks a lot to everybody for notifying us about this
> issue. We have been able to reproduce and fix it. Please do let us
> know (in a comment to this answer) if you're still encountering any
> issues with this.

Там поблагодарили всех причастных и рапортавали о том, что данную ошибку пофиксили.

Статус обновили до `status-completed`